# Microsoft Acces throwing an error msg while trying to execute an SQL SELECT

Tags: sql, ms-access

When I try to run this SQL SELECT statement in Microsoft Access I get an error message:

```
SELECT (tblBestelldetails.Einzelpreis * tblBestelldetails.Anzahl) AS Barwert
     , tblKunden.Firma, Count(tbl.BestellungID)
FROM (tblBestellungen 
INNER JOIN tblBestelldetails 
   ON tblBestellungen.BestellungID = tblBestelldetails.BestellungID) 
INNER JOIN tblKunden 
   ON tblBestellungen.KundeID = tblKunden.KundeID;
```

It works, however fails once I add the `Count(tbl.BestellungID)` field into the SELECT Statement. Also, I know I would have to group it by `BestellungID` later on but I tried that and it didn't fix my issue.

The weird thing is once I add the `Count(tbl.BestellungID)` it says that

> The parameter (tblBestelldetails.Einzelpreis * tblBestelldetails.Anzahl) AS Barwert doesn't work because it isn't a aggregation function.

Does anybody know how I can fix this?

Comment: You need to group by all non-aggregated fields.  `GROUP BY (tblBestelldetails.Einzelpreis * tblBestelldetails.Anzahl)
       , tblKunden.Firma`  you can't group by Barwert as that alias isn't known to the group by due to order of operations of a select statement.  (FROM, joins, Group By, Select, having, Order by)

Comment: Generally you *don't* want to group by fields that you are using in an aggregate function. You usually want to group by other fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to group by all non-aggregated fields.

`(tblBestelldetails.Einzelpreis * tblBestelldetails.Anzahl)` isn't an aggregate unless you add a sum (or other aggregate), so you have to group by the same formula that is in the select. One can not use the alias in the aggregation as the alias is not know at the time the group by is evaluated by the DB engine.  So you need to include the formula in the group by.

```
SELECT (tblBestelldetails.Einzelpreis * tblBestelldetails.Anzahl) AS Barwert
     , tblKunden.Firma
     , Count(tblBestellungen .BestellungID) 
FROM (tblBestellungen 
INNER JOIN tblBestelldetails 
   ON tblBestellungen.BestellungID = tblBestelldetails.BestellungID) 
INNER JOIN tblKunden 
   ON tblBestellungen.KundeID = tblKunden.KundeID
GROUP BY (tblBestelldetails.Einzelpreis * tblBestelldetails.Anzahl)
       , tblKunden.Firma
```

Perhaps you need to aggregate barwert as well..
It looks like you have a 1-M-1 relationship between tblBestellungen-tblBestelldetails - tblKunden.

So maybe we just need to aggregate the details and group by firma.

```
SELECT sum(tblBestelldetails.Einzelpreis * tblBestelldetails.Anzahl) AS Barwert
     , tblKunden.Firma
     , Count(tblBestellungen.BestellungID) 
FROM (tblBestellungen 
INNER JOIN tblBestelldetails 
   ON tblBestellungen.BestellungID = tblBestelldetails.BestellungID) 
INNER JOIN tblKunden 
   ON tblBestellungen.KundeID = tblKunden.KundeID
GROUP BY tblKunden.Firma
```

Or.... maybe you're not enforcing db integrity and need to distinct the IDs?

```
SELECT (tblBestelldetails.Einzelpreis * tblBestelldetails.Anzahl) AS Barwert
     , tblKunden.Firma
     , Count(distinct tblBestellungen.BestellungID) 
FROM (tblBestellungen 
INNER JOIN tblBestelldetails 
   ON tblBestellungen.BestellungID = tblBestelldetails.BestellungID) 
INNER JOIN tblKunden 
   ON tblBestellungen.KundeID = tblKunden.KundeID
GROUP BY (tblBestelldetails.Einzelpreis * tblBestelldetails.Anzahl)
       ,  tblKunden.Firma
```

Comment: Thanks alot the error doesnt accure anymore! But do you have an idea why it could return the wrong amout of Bestellungen on the Count?
I tried only getting the amount of "Bestellungen" with this Select and it works:

SELECT COUNT(tblBestellungen.BestellungID)
FROM tblBestellungen INNER JOIN tblBestelldetails ON tblBestellungen.BestellungID = tblBEstelldetails.BestellungID
GROUP BY tblBestellungen.BestellungID;

So how can i implement that into the main select?

Comment: Without a better understanding of the tables and what you're trying to accomplish, the only option I can see is `count(distinct BestellungID)`  Likely what's happening is the one to many relationship between bestellungen and bestelldetails is inflating the count; by using distinct we only count unique bestellungIDs  for the firma.  Now, you may also want to remove the formula in the group by and use a sum... I'll give an example.

Comment: Thank you sososo mutch. The first option worked perfectly!